# RPG: determine pressed key

Tags: ibm-midrange

is there a possibility to determine which key was pressed in RPG program (work with display file) using some indicators? I know that it is feasible for function or some command keys. But I need to determine keys like: '+', 'S', '/' etc. Are there some codes for all keyboard keys?

Thanks in advance for some clue,
JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using straight 5250 emulation, no there is not any way to detect most keystrokes.

If you are using a browser based interface, perhaps RPG Open Access, it is a different story.  With Profound UI or other such avenues, you are able to use javascript in the browser, which does give you access to keystrokes.

Another option would be to gain low level access inside the 5250 emulator.  This could be done by using an open source emulator such as TN5250J.

Comment: Unfortunately, I use 5250 emulator. Thanks for your answer. Now I have no doubts about this case.

Comment: Well, as I said, you could consider using an open source emulator such as TN5250J.  Then you would be able to work at the client side and access keystrokes.  The problem would be knowing when to do so in an emulation session, and what you would do with keystroke information at that point.  You might be biting off more than you had hoped for.

Answer (score 5):

Workstation display files are block (record) mode devices and I don't know of a way to capture individual keys as all of that processing occurs within the terminal itself.

See the [Application Display programming](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/rzakc/sc415715.pdf) book for details.